# Angular component naming limitations - 'selector [your component name] is invalid'

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, angular-cli, angular6

In `Angular 6` (6.0.7) I'm trying to generate a component via the CLI. I type in `ng g c t1-2-3-user` and get the error message ***`Selector (app-t1-2-3-user) is invalid.`***

Is there something inherently not allowed in this name? I've already created a parent module called `t1-myModule` via `ng g module t1-myModule` and it was created successfully. Within that module is where I'm trying to generate this component.

I've tried creating a different name like `ng g c t1-testComponent` and it works fine - so the CLI doesn't appear to be broken. Something about naming a component `t1-2-3-user` in my setup is not liked by Angular.

**EDIT:** **after further testing, it appears Angular doesn't like the first character after a dash `-` to be a number. Possibly a similar limitation as in JavaScript variables. I assume since it gets compiled into JavaScript? Can anyone elaborate on/confirm this component naming constraint?**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As per [**W3C standards**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters) selector should qualify below set of things

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain
>
> 1. only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_);
> 2. they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by
>      a digit
> 3. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

So Angular is following the W3C convention for selector name. I was expected to see similar thing baked in inside code somewhere. After digging into CLI code It turns out that angular uses regex (`/^[a-zA-Z][.0-9a-zA-Z]*(:?-[a-zA-Z][.0-9a-zA-Z]*)*$/`) to validate `selector` name before creating files.

So while running `ng generate component component-name` command it calls `@angular/schematics` for `component` command and pass the component name parameter to it. While executing command with set of instruction it fires [below line](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/schematics/angular/component/index.ts#L147) to validate selector.

```
validateHtmlSelector(options.selector);
```

[**validation.ts**](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/schematics/angular/utility/validation.ts#L20)

```
export const htmlSelectorRe = /^[a-zA-Z][.0-9a-zA-Z]*(:?-[a-zA-Z][.0-9a-zA-Z]*)*$/;
export function validateHtmlSelector(selector: string): void {
  if (selector && !htmlSelectorRe.test(selector)) {
    throw new SchematicsException(tags.oneLine`Selector (${selector})
        is invalid.`);
  }
}
```