# How to generate an Angular component with an attribute selector via Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I would like to generate a component like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '[appTest]', // <-- attribute selector 
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Normally, I would use the command
`ng g c test`
which generates a component with an element selector

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

But when I try to specify the selector: `ng g c test --selector="[appTest]"` 
it throws this error:

```
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"style":"scss","spec":false,"selector":"[appTest]","name":"test","project":"client"}
Errors:

  Data path ".selector" should match format "html-selector".
```

the `--selector` cli option validates against a regex that doesn't allow these attribute selectors:

`export const htmlSelectorRe = /^[a-zA-Z][.0-9a-zA-Z]*(:?-[a-zA-Z][.0-9a-zA-Z]*)*$/;`

(reference: [Angular component naming limitations - 'selector [your component name] is invalid'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231588/angular-component-naming-limitations-selector-your-component-name-is-invalid))

**is there a way to generate via cli a component with a bracketed (like `[appTest]`) attribute selector?**

Answer (score 0):

If there exist only one, changing the schematics root in angular. That’s extremely hard and difficult so I should have to say there is not a possibility. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is only possible to create assign a selector that begins with a letter and that contains only alphanumeric characters or dashes.

[The following line](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/schematics/angular/utility/validation.ts#L22) of official angular source code reports this.

You can request a new feature by [submitting an issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#submit-issue) to [GitHub Angular/CLI Repository](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) .