# is it allowed to reverse angular component selector prefix to be a suffix?

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint, codelyzer

I have an angular app with a custom prefix for example `myApp` that generates the components selectors in this way `<myApp-nav></myApp-nav>`.
for some reasons i need it  to be `<nav-myApp></nav-myApp>` .
another way cant go with it to add special characters to be `<$-nav></$-nav>` or `<$myApp-nav></$myApp-nav>` .
i got `Selector ($myApp-nav) is invalid.`

Comment: There's no *technical* requirement for a prefix, it's part of the [style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#component-custom-prefix) to avoid clashes with any other library that's providing elements which a suffix would also achieve. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/53231588/3001761 for the actual requirements.

Comment: yes looks good, I updated the question by the error I got when I use a custom prefix.

Comment: Your custom prefix still needs to be valid as part of a selector per the question I linked above: https://regex101.com/r/jD2H3s/1

Comment: _"is it allowed to reverse angular component selector prefix to be a suffix?"_ Yes, you don't even need a prefix or suffix.

Comment: yes manually, is there is a way through the cli?

Comment: AFAIK that's all configured in the schematics and you can create and install your own schematics.